# Understanding `od -c` output

Tags: od

I've got a text file that I'm trying to debug an encoding issue in. I ran the file through `od -c` and got the following output:

```
3457540  ,   "   t   e   x   t   "   :   "   302 241   Q   u 303 251
```

My understanding from the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?od) is that -c "select[s] ASCII characters or backslash escapes." I guess I don't understand what a backslash escape is. I would have assumed it to be a C-string style escaped character, such as `\0` or `\n`. However, I'm getting values (302 and 303) that are clearly out of the range of a byte. Could somebody explain what's happening here?

Comment: Guess what `o` means in `od` ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Yeah, I knew that it meant octal dump, but apparently I'm having a derp day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those numbers are *octal* (base 8)  It'll only backslash something that has a symbolic name (`\n`, `\b`, `\t`, etc.)

(I prefer `hd` -- `hexdump -C` -- myself.)

Comment: Ah, I forgot that a lot of these tools were written for octal first. That would explain the oddball numbers. Thanks, hd looks like the better option. FYI, the -c switch is lower case (at least on Ubuntu).

Comment: No, lowercase "c" is different from uppercase for the parent `hexdump` application.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking `hd` was an alias for `hexdump`. Thanks again.